# Idea for algorithm to arrange balls of different weights into boxes

Tags: algorithm, performance, optimization, combinatorics

### The problem

Suppose I have some balls and box types:

- Each ball has a different weight.
- Each type of box has its **min** and **max** capacity, and a **penalty** when used.
- There are unlimited number of boxes for each type.

How can I arrange the balls into the least boxes such that:

- The total **weight** of the balls in each box is **within** its min and max capacity.
- The total **penalty** of the used boxes is **minimized**.
- There may be multiple solutions. However, the accepted solution is where the total **weight** of the balls in each box is **nearest** to its **max** capacity.

### Example

For example, there are 5 balls of weight 31, 14, 13, 12, 7 respectively, and 3 box types:

```
type│ min │ max │penalty
────┼─────┼─────┼───────
 A  │  11 │  20 │    1
 B  │  21 │  30 │    1
 C  │  31 │  40 │    5
```

The possible combinations are:

```
boxTypes│ 31 │ 14 │ 13 │ 12 │  7 │ penalty
────────┼────┼────┼────┼────┼────┼─────────
   ABC  │ C  │ B  │ B  │ A  │ C  │    7
   BBC  │ C  │ B1 │ B2 │ B2 │ B1 │    7
    CC  │ C1 │ C2 │ C2 │ C2 │ C1 │   10
   ACC  │ C1 │ C2 │ C2 │ A  │ C2 │   11
```

and many other unlisted possibilities where the set of box types are the same or the penalty is just too high.

Notice that there are 2 solutions with the same penalty. However, considering the third condition:

```
boxTypes │ box1 │ box2 │ box3 │            shortfall
─────────┼──────┼──────┼──────┼──────────────────────────────────
  ABC    │  12  │  27  │  38  │ (20-12) + (30-27) + (40-38) = 13
  BBC    │  21  │  25  │  31  │ (30-25) + (30-25) + (40-31) = 19
```

The **ABC** box combination is chosen due to filling the most capacity of the boxes.

### My code

I am currently recursively generating all combinations of the balls, and check whether there is a set of box that fits the ball groups.

I am able to improve the performance by:

- **Early halt** when a group weight is out of the maximum capacity (40 in this example)
- **Limit** the number of boxes (2 - 3 instead of 5, i.e. 1 box for each ball)

However, my solution still cannot handle more than 15 balls.

---

Is there a better algorithm other than bruteforce to solve this problem?

Comment: Check out [Integer-Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming). A first attempt is relatively straighforward to model, if you infer some upper bounds for box-cardinalities (e.g. at most 5 boxes of type C). Further attempts might dive into symmetry-breaking stuff and such. But be careful. A formal approach is highly recommended. In your case it's not really formally described how your objective works. A multi-objective opt is indicated, but the usual questions then are: linearized multi-obj vs. lexicographic vs. ?; linear vs. quadratic penalty (sums vs. box-capacities).

Comment: I would try https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm for the best way to put the balls into the boxes. As a practical optimization, I would sort the balls from biggest to smallest, and I would use the best heuristic I can, even if it is expensive to calculate. Because better heuristic = less backtracking = avoid exponential time+memory.